# Remove .php extension and add one slash

Tags: .htaccess, web

good day

i am just stuck in the middle of something i want to remove .php extension and make one slash for example

my current url is

http://example.com/campus.php?college=BGIET,%20Sangrur

Now i want to change it to

http://example.com/campus/BGIET,Sangrur

Is it possible to do this i am clueless to how to make this happen

**and yes /mod_rewrite is enabled**

proof :-

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^google.html$ http://www.google.com/ [R=301]
```

Going to http://www.example.com/google.html redirecting to Google.com so it is enabled..

help me out please ( ._.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /campus\.php\?college=([^\s&]+)\%20([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ campus/%1%2? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /campus\.php\?college=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ campus/%1%2? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^campus/(.+?)/?$ campus.php?college=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `.htaccess` in your web root `/` directory

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /campus\.php\?college=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /campus/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # not a dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # not a file
RewriteRule ^campus/(.*)$ /campus.php?college=$1 [NC,L]
```

The first rule makes sure that if the old URL is used, the user gets redirected to the new one automatically. The second rule resolves the non-php link to the php one behind the scenes.

Comment: really appreciated you answer but it is showing "Internal Server Error"

Comment: Any other rules in your htaccess?

Comment: no i just putted your code only. and it is showing "Internal Server Error"

Comment: Which url are you using to access the site?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71932/discussion-between-ayan-aman-and-ravi-thapliyal).